# Typeorm update set from select

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

i have the following query.

```
update
"document"
set
"documentNumber" = a."documentNumber" + 1
from (
select
d."documentNumber" from "document" d where d."documentAreaId" = 1 order by d."documentNumber" desc limit 1
) as a
where id = 29497
RETURNING *;
```

How to do this in typeorm?

Comment: if you need a raw query, you can use manager.query (ex: `await manager.query('SELECT * FROM users')`). [manager.query](https://typeorm.io/entity-manager-api). If you need work with entities, you can use query builder [query builder](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#)

Comment: thank you. yes i know the two but i was unable to do this with queryBuilder and didnt want to use raw query. The nested select is troublesome for me when using queryBuilder

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the query builder or is the only way to do it by using raw sql?